# Creating a Git Branch structure to support separation of concern

Tags: git, android-studio, github, branch

## Background

I created a new Git Repo from Android Studio with 1 branch that holds all my code, and I am want to create a new branch structure to kind of perform separation of concerns.

My [current module structure](https://github.com/ciscorucinski/Accessibility) is contains modules called `accessibility` (my library code - functions as the `app` module), and `samples`. It also has generic project files (like `gradlew`, `settings.gradle`, etc...) and meta files (like `.gitignore`, `README`, etc...).

## What I want to do...

I want to create the following...

- a branch that contains all the merged version of all the following branches
- `dev` branch that only contains the `accessibility` module and the required project files
- `Meta` branch that contains only meta files like the `README`, `.gitignore`, license file, etc...
- `samples` branch that I think will need to include the `accessibility` module due to the samples application using the code in that module. However, I would like to keep it as lean as possible, meaning I would prefer if the `accessibility` module was not included.

...and these branches should not contain any files that are unnecessary for that branch

## What I have done...

In Android studio, I have created the necessary branches, but they are only local branches apparently. I have tried to add the `README` and `.gitignore` file to the new `meta` branch; however, I cannot seem to add the individual files to that branch.

I don't know if each of the branches are identical and all have the same files in them, or if they are empty, or what. I cannot push to Github because they don't have changes.

Is this even possible? I know I can create a small branch that will be merged to the main branch when a feature is finished; however, this seems a different from that.

Note: I don't have a lot of experience with git in the command line

Comment: I would use separate *repositories* rather than separate *branches* for this sort of separation.  Your life will be easier if branches within a repository represent changes to the same common code, rather than completely separate projects.

Comment: @larsks but a lot of library repos contain a sample module, so this would still be considered one project and not 2 or more projects. What I was thinking is that the `meta` stuff like the README and such would be its own "feature" branch that I would merge into master. Same with the "sample feature" that would be merged into master. Instead of temp feature branches that get closed, I would have several permanent "feature" branches. Is that would you originally I meant thought?